# How to add values in dropdown list using java servlet

Tags: servlets

This is the code for Drop Down List. Now I want to know how add values in dropdown list using java servlet

```
<select name="Day">
    <option>Day</option>
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use the c tag library and Expression Language to loop through your request object.

Example (modify as necessary):

Import the c tag Library in your JSP:

```
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
```

Modify your Select:

```
<select name="Day">
     <c:forEach items="${requestVariableName}" var="dayOption" >
          <option>${dayOption}</option>
     </c:forEach>
</select>
```